# FitsSystemWindows with translucent status bar and action bar tabs

Tags: android, translucentdecor

In the app I am currently working on, I am working on implementing the translucent status bar with action bar tabs. I hide the ActionBar and only show the tabs.

My problem is that now, the system lets space for the action bar that is not there so FitsSystemWindows is making an error.

How can I fix that?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm having the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual solution that time was quite dirty: I needed to set a custom padding from the top (I think it was 47dp or something like that) to the ViewPager (I think it was the ViewPager).

The real solution has come with AppCompat that fixes such issues: So use AppCompat!